# Is there a difference between <> and NOT LIKE operator in this case

Tags: ms-access

Would there be any difference between

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column <> "aa"`

and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column NOT LIKE "aa"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<> will not evaluate wild cards
<> '%' is a search on literal %

There are more "wild cards" than % _

These are not the same

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],[word]
  FROM [FTSwordDef]
  where [word] like '[a-z]a'


  SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],[word]
  FROM [FTSwordDef]
  where [word] = '[a-z]a'
```

Use <> when you have a literal match

Use LIKE when you want to use "wild cards"